# Django Ajax simple Get function

Tags: ajax, json, django, get

First of all, sorry for stupid question but I'm no coder, so please forgive me :)

I've written simple code in Python which is reading data send through serial port. 
It's working really great.

EDIT:

With your help vadimchin I have managed to do something like this.

views.py

```
class ViewVolt(TemplateView):
template_name = 'view_volt.html'

def __init__(self, voltage=''):
    self.voltage = voltage
    rs232 = serial.Serial(
                     port = 'COM15',
                     baudrate = 38400,
                     parity = serial.PARITY_NONE,
                     stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
                     bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
                     timeout = 1) 
    line = rs232.readline().decode('utf-8')
    if ( 'Pomiar 1' in line ):
        index_current = line.find('Prąd')
        index_voltage = line.find('Napięcie')
        current = line[index_current+6:index_current+11]
        self.voltage = line[index_voltage+9:index_voltage+14] 

def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):

    context = super(ViewVolt, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
    context['ajax_var'] = self.voltage
    context['is_ajax'] = self.request.is_ajax()
    return context
```

What I'm trying to do for now is to display only voltage value on my webpage.

urls.py

```
url(r'^volt/$', ViewVolt.as_view(), name='view_volt'),
```

view_volt.html

```
    {% if is_ajax %}
    <h1>from ajax: {{ ajax_var }}</h1>
{% else %}
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="{{ STATIC_URL }}admin/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function () {
                var ping_tm = null;

                function _ping() {
                    $.get('', function (result) {
                        clearTimeout(ping_tm);
                        $("div").empty();
                        $("div").append(result);

                        ping_tm = setTimeout(_ping, 1000);
                    })
                }

                _ping();

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div></div>
    my doc
    </body>
    </html>
{% endif %}
```

As you can see I have modified little bit your view_volt.html template and your View_volt class but it's still does not work as it should be.

Here's a screenshoot.

![Result[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JIiah.jpg)]

I have no idea why it's not getting the value's from my serial port all the time.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

views.py

```
logger = logging.getLogger('volt')

class ViewVolt(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'frontend/view_volt.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ViewVolt, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        logger.debug('my info')

        context['ajax_var'] = '1234'
        context['is_ajax'] = self.request.is_ajax()
        return context
```

view_volt.html

```
{% if is_ajax %}
    <h1>from ajax: {{ ajax_var }}</h1>
{% else %}
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(function () {
                var ping_tm = null;

                function _ping() {
                    $.get('', function (result) {
                        clearTimeout(ping_tm);

                        console.log(result);

                        ping_tm = setTimeout(_ping, 1000);
                    })
                }

                _ping();

            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    my doc
    </body>
    </html>
{% endif %}
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
   url(r'^volt/$', ViewVolt.as_view(), name='view_volt'),
)
```

Ore you can use websocket + gevent

in settings.py add

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        },
        'file': {
           'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
           'level': 'DEBUG',
           'filename': 'log.log'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
        'volt': {
           'handlers': ['file'],
           'level': 'DEBUG'
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: How this variable {{ ajax_var }} can be displayed under http://localhost:8000/volt/ while it's not within <body></body> tags ?

Comment: replace console.log(result) for example - $('body').append(result)

Comment: vadimchin: I have modified your code a little bit and Im one step closer to achive my goal but I struggle with another problem described above.

Comment: try to use logging (see modified code), and maybe you need move all data from constructor into get_context_data